# Multiple types of media held in playlist in Java

Tags: java, list, media

I'm currently trying to write a playlist in Java.

The idea is that it can support many different types of media...

Music: mp3, flac, wav, etc
Video: avi mp4 etc
Music/Video from weblinks

I'm planning to maintain all these in one list. I'm trying to figure out a best approach. Should I implement a common interface for MediaItem which agrees a contract needed for each media item type (represented by different classes) or should I deal with all types in one class?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: IMO 'a) the interface'  Please don't add sigs. to the text of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the javaFx libraries offer a Class called Media which represents different types of media.